# Dynamic Collapsable Flow Chart Online

Tags: dynamic, flowchart

Been looking through a number of other related posts relating to flowchart software.

I have been asked to put together a document outlining some of the typical problems our users encounter with our software product.
What I would like to do, is create an interactive/online flowchart that lets users choose from 4-5 overall headings on whats wrong.  Then for this to dynamically expand more choices on pinpointing the problem, and so on and so on, until they can get a resolution to their problem.

The key thing that I have not been able to find in some of the flowchart software out there, is having the click + expand element.
- I dont want all options to appear to the end-user in a huge flow chart as it will distract away from their specific issue.
- I want them to be able to click away and go down a specific avenue that will end up giving them some good things to try, based on their decisions/clicks.

I was originally thinking of perhaps putting something in Flex or Silverlight (ideally someone would have a template out there) but am now thinking of taking advantage of 3rd party (ideally free) software.

This will need to be hosted in a browser.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have been trialling this: hindin.co.nz/Products/MapIT.htm (Click on the View Example Script for a demo) I like the way it walks you through with a series of multiple choice questions. Anyone seen something similar to this?

Comment: Hey Simon, I've also been looking desperately for the same concept application that you were. Were you successful in finding one? Thanks!

Comment: Still looking. As an interim, I used Visio to just create basic flowcharts, but they were not collapsible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). It's mind mapping software, so not necessarily a flowcharting tool, but you can use it for what you describe.